# Permutation returning True or False python

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to make a function `isPerm(P)` that returns `True` if it is a permutation, and `False` otherwise.

So far I've got:

```
def isPerm(P):
    if len(P) == list(range(P)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: @thefourtheye of a list

Comment: Please update your question with a sample input and expected output. The question leaves people guessing.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way which I can think of is to use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

def isPerm(P, Q):
    return Counter(P) == Counter(Q)

print isPerm("oolegg", "google")
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easy solution, for short lists.

```
def is_perm(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach: sort a clone of the list and then compare the original list with the sorted clone. If equal then you have a permutation. But sorting takes time.

Efficient approach: create a dictionary/counter with items set to 0 and loop through the list increasing the value in the dictionary. If you get a value of `0` or greater that 1 after finishing the list then you don't have a permutation.